# Geometric series word problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I was given a question that said : 
A person has 2/3 of a cake in the fridge, and to make it last longer, they decide to only eat half of what was left each day. If this person has a serving each day, how much of the cake have they eaten?

I assumed that the common ratio between each amount every day was 1/2. So therefore, after every serving, half of the previous amount would be left. So if servings are X and amount left is Y, then for X = 1, Y should be 1/3. And so forth. My answer so far was that she had eaten 47/48 of the cake by the 5th serving. Is this correct?

EDIT : To be clear, the starting amount of the cake is 2/3. The person eats 1/2 of what was there before each serving. So for the first serving, they eat 1/3 (half of 2/3). The next serving, they eat half of 1/3.

Comment: The question isn't clear.  How much have they eaten *when*?

Comment: She started with $\frac 23$.  $\frac {47}{48} > \frac 23$.  How can she eat more than she started with?

Comment: Each day she eats half of what's left, leaving half.  After $5$ days only $(\frac 1{2}^5 = \frac 1{32}$ will be left.  So $\frac 1{32}$ of $\frac 23 = \frac 1{48}$ of the cake left.  As she started with $\frac 23$ and she ended up with $\frac 1{48}$ so she at $\frac 23 - \frac 1{48} = \frac {31}{32}$ of the cake.

Comment: Ok ill try to clear this up more. Each SERVING is half the previous amount. So she starts with 2/3, and one serving then brings her to 1/3.

Comment: But she still can't eat more than what she started with.  If each serving is half the previous serving then the first to fifth servings are $\frac 13, \frac 16, \frac 1{12}, \frac 1{24}, \frac 1{48}$ and in total she has eaten $\frac {31}{48}$ of the cake.

Comment: @fleablood, how did you get that though? When 1/48 is left, does that not mean she has eaten 2/3 of 47/48? Can you explain how you get 31/48?

Comment: I've already explained it twice.  $\frac 23-\frac {1}{48}= \frac {31}{48} $.  Also $\frac 23 (\frac 12+\frac 14+...\frac 1 {32})=\frac {31}{48} $.

Answer (score 1):

After $n$ servings, what is left is $\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2^n}$. What the person ate is $\frac{2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2^n}$. Your answer assumes that the first $1/3$ of the cake was also eaten by these people. You did $1-\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{2^n}$.